# Change CKeditor direction dynamically

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I've check numerous questions on SO but couldn't achieve required behaviour.
I have registered an on change listener on ckeditor instance, when a charecter is typed I check if the language is persian or not.
If the language is persian, direction should be changed to RTL automatically.

Similiar question has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46314615/how-to-dynamically-switch-text-direction-in-ckeditor) but reinitializing the editor doesn't create a nice ux.

Another approach I tried was to change config of the editor on the fly, but apparently Ckeditor ignores it completely.
the way I did was:

```
CKEDITOR.replace('editor1', newConfig);
```

So my question is: how do I change ckeditor's direction on the fly without reinitializing the instance?

Answer (score 1):

You could take a look at [BiDi](https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/bidi) plugin which allows to change text direction of any block-level element (e.g. paragraphs) - see [this SDK sample](https://sdk.ckeditor.com/samples/language.html).

So if on [change](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/docs/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-event-change) event you detect that Persian was typed, you may automatically update the block-level element `dir` attribute (that's what `BiDi` plugin is using). To get block-level element based on current selection take a look at [elementPath](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/docs/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-method-elementPath) and its [block](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/docs/#!/api/CKEDITOR.dom.elementPath-property-block) property.

Comment: Thanks, will try and inform.

Comment: Actually I don't remember how could I do that. Are you stuck at it? I might be able to help you.